# Ошибка при резке картинки.

Tags: изображения, php

Есть код:

```
  $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);
  imagecopyresampled($new_image, '../temp/'.$NameImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 200, 0, 90);
```

Я не могу понять почему от возращяет ошибку: Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in /home/11/w.ru/upload/links.php on line 19

Answer (score 1):

Вы сделали ресурс функцией imagecreatetruecolor(). 2-й параметр тоже должен быть ресурсом.

Вот пример кода из [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecopyresampled.php)

```
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Читайте, что написано в ошибке, это важно, если вы пишите код, который хотите заставить работать:

> expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given

Из документации по php:

```
bool imagecopyresampled ( resource $dst_image , resource $src_image , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $dst_w , int $dst_h , int $src_w , int $src_h )
```

Второй параметр функции должен быть не строкой (вы видимо указали путь), а ресурсом картинки. Загляните в [документацию](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php#refsect1-function.imagecopyresampled-examples), там есть примеры использования.

Comment: и действительно) чет туплю) спасибо!